Panel regression model with market share as dependent variable
The data set consists of different variables from different banks during 6 years. I want to understand how these variables correlate with market share. The problem is that market share is a zero-sum game. If market share for one bank increases then the market share for another bank automatically decreases. How should I combat this? I have tried logit transformation for fixed effects and vector autoregression but it is not great.

Compositional data analysis is one way to handle this type of problem. This question seems closely related to yours.
